# Scrapy meta or cb_kwargs not passing properly between multiple methods

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping a fitness website.

I have different methods like, scraping home page, category wise and product information, I am trying to pass all these level information in a dictionary using meta/ cb_kwargs.

code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals

class FitSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fit'
    allowed_domains = ['www.f.........com']
    

    category_counter = product_counter = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(FitSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return spider
    
    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        print("SPIDER CLOSED")
        print("Category Counter length")
        print(self.category_counter)
        print("product counter length")
        print(self.product_counter)
        spider.logger.info('Spider closed: %s', spider.name)
    
    
    def start_requests(self):
        ...
        ...
        ...
        search_url ='...' #from my code.
        
        yield scrapy.Request(url=search_url,
                            meta=info_dict,
                            callback=self.parse
                            )
    
    def parse(self,response):
        info_dict = response.meta
        #parsing and additing additional keys to info_dict
        ...
        ...
        categories = [....,...,...]
        for category in categories:
            category_url = ...
            
            yield scrapy.Request(url=category_url,
                        meta=info_dict,
                        callback=self.parse_by_category)
    
    def parse_by_category(self,response):
        info_dict = response.meta
        
        #parse and add additional info to info_dict
        ...
        ...
        products = [...,...,...]
        
        for product in products:
        
            self.category_counter += 1
            
            yield scrapy.Request(url=pro_url,
                    cb_kwargs=info_dict.copy(),
                    callback=self.get_product_info)
        
    
    def get_product_info(self,response,**kwargs):
    
        self.product_counter += 1
        meta_data = kwargs
        
        #parse and scrape product info, yield final dict
        
        ...
        ...
        meta_data["product_name"] = ...

        yield meta_data
```

problem:

I have two variables to monitor, how many times `parse_by_category` and `get_product_info` are called and the counter variables initiated are `category_counter` and `product_counter` respectively.

I am calling `get_product_info` method for every product (132 products in total), the `self.product_counter` should be 132 but it just yielded only 3 times.

I also used scrapy signal to check the counters, and its output.

```
SPIDER CLOSED
Category Counter length
132
product counter length
3
```

> self.category_counter works fine - 132 times,

> but self.product_counter - only 3 times,

**Execution logs**

```
SPIDER CLOSED
Category Counter length
132
product counter length
3
2020-10-24 05:49:28 [fit] INFO: Spider closed: fit
2020-10-24 05:49:28 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 53795,
 'downloader/request_count': 70,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 70,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1873858,
 'downloader/response_count': 70,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 70,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 129,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 85.653364,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 24, 5, 49, 28, 413804),
 'item_scraped_count': 3,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 214,
 'log_count/INFO': 13,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'memusage/max': 140091392,
 'memusage/startup': 96174080,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 70,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 69,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 69,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 69,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 69,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 24, 5, 48, 2, 760440)}
2020-10-24 05:49:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Not sure what I am missing, kindly help.

Comment: Can you share an execution log? I assume the items yielded are also only 3?

Comment: updated with logs, please check

Comment: @renatodvc anything else needed?

Comment: You might wanna consider trying [deepcopy()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#scrapy.item.Item.deepcopy)